# Weird: Why my WebView Project works with iPhone but shows blank with iPad?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

Update: I have recreated the same steps with a new project targeting iPhone and this time it works; I tried again with iPad only project it doesn't! That's weird isn't it ?

Update2: I found why. I saw blank because I put default webview size control and I can see something only if I rotate the iPad simulator :(

====
In xib file I have drag and drop a UIWebView control in my single view app for IPAD Simulator

I drag and drop from the control to file owner to set the delegate
I drag and drop from the file owner to set webView in referencing Outlets

In code I have

// h file

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

// m file

```
#import "myViewController.h"

@interface myViewController ()

@end

@implementation myViewController

@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // try following complete url   
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.google.com";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: have you link the webView object declered in your header file with webview in xib

Comment: I guess so as I said " I drag and drop from the file owner to set webView in referencing Outlets" ?

Comment: then its perfect your code should work...just try by adding webview delegate in header file,and debug by using webview delegates like
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView

Comment: are you sure that you are having internet connection for device...??jst kidding

Comment: nothing matters even if you add www even simple google.com without www is working in my case with same code

Comment: Update: I have recreated the same steps with a new project targeting iPhone and this time it works; I tried again with iPad only project it doesn't! That's weird isn't it ?

Answer (score 2):

try that you have connect webview outlet in interfacebuilder and  see following code give complete url

```
  NSString *urlAddress = @”http://www.google.com”;

 //Create a URL object.
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
  NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
  [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: OK thanks it was just mistypo. I have recreated the same steps with a new project targeting iPhone and this time it works; I tried again with iPad only project it doesn't! That's weird isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try & check by encoding the string url :

```
 urlString=[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

may your url is incorrect

try this

```
  NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";
```